# how to load php extention @dl('ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so') dynamically in php 5.3

Tags: php

I am trying to load php extension @dl('ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so') dynamically , but gives me fatal error :call to undefined function dl(). Then I searched alternative for it in php 5.3 but not able to find right information, kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs of [**`dl()`**](http://php.net/dl):

> 5.3.0:    dl() is now disabled in some SAPIs due to stability issues. The only SAPIs that allow dl() are CLI and Embed. Use the [Extension Loading Directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) instead.

You need to add the extension to your php.ini: `extension=/path/to/extension/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so`

Comment: Thank u! so much. will u please give me example of how do I Use the Extension Loading Directives for ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so extension

Comment: As I wrote underneath the quote, just add this in a new line of your php.ini (for Apache2 it would be: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`). And then restart your server for enabling the extension.

Comment: Well that's it then, after restarting your server, the extension should be available.

Comment: +1. write a script `<?php phpinfo();`, open it in a browser, and see if there is ioncube in the extension list, and if not, open the php.ini (the path to it is shown on that same page) and add it there. The restart the http daemon.

Comment: thank you , it is showing in php_info(); I also checked  from terminal by using php -v , it is installed perfectly,but still giving me the error call to undefined method dl();

Comment: Because you don't need `dl()` anymore. It was removed and replaced by the method above! It's now enabled by default and you can work with it.